# Syncing iCloud Drive to my Mac immediately creates 100 GB of system storage - OS Monterey

Tags: macos, icloud, storage

I love iCloud and have been using it since forever. I understand that iCloud Drive is not a perfect cloud feature and is mostly about syncing files across devices. As an owner of an iPad, 2 Macbooks, and 2 iPhones, I really love iCloud.

The problem started when my Macbook Air for work became glitchy as I was lacking enough free space. I did a factory reboot and downloaded the new OS Monterey (yay!). Just in case, I didn't reboot through Time Machine back up. I wanted the Macbook as clean as possible. As soon as I synced my iCloud Drive, i gained 97 GB of system storage and I was again out of storage (121 GB Macbook Air)

I got angry and unsynced my iCloud Drive.

Double checked that Time Machine was never on after the reboot.

And then I deleted my cached files through Finder > option Go > Library > Caches.

= 12.4 GB of system storage

I became happier and decided to sync iCloud Drive again (because I need the easy navigation for work), but then system data started increasing and became 97 GB *again*.

I assume that a *stuck* "Waiting to Download" (*not* upload) iCloud action is the culprit of this mess. But I have no method of tracking this action and deleting it. And now, I can't sync iCloud Drive to my Mac. This is *very* frustrating.

Need solutions for the below:

- Reason why syncing iCloud Drive would immediately cause a 90 gb increase of system data
- How to isolate the system data associated with my iCloud Drive
- How to delete the associated system data so that I can sync my iCloud Drive with my Macbook again.

Please help.

Went through *three* calls with Apple Support and no help for now.

Apple community: [Syncing iCloud Drive to my Mac immediately creates 100gb of system storage - OS Monterey](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254055332)

Comment: 90GB sounds to me like video/photo data. Is keep originals or somethin alike in the icloud settings turned on?

Comment: What makes you think there's a "stuck waiting to download iCloud action"?

Comment: Photos is not synced. All documents data is stored on my external hard drive!!! @X_841

Comment: @benwiggy - When I briefly synced iCloud Drive to the Mac, a circular pie chart came up and when I clicked it, it said so.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I wouldn't pay too much attention to the Storage 'breakdown' in About This Mac. System Data is, really, "everything else". (Mine is currently 60Gb.)

If you're running out of space, check out how much space your entire User account takes up. Also, how many applications have you added, and how much space do they take? These are going to be the largest quantities.

Secondly, deleting caches achieves nothing, as they will be recreated by the OS.

It's possible that iCloud has got itself into some sort of mess, but I would try to leave it and let it complete.

Once that's done, use an app like [OmniDiskSweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/more) (free) to browse through your disk, sorted by file size. This will show you what and where the biggest files are, and let you delete them, if necessary.

Comment: Well, I just booted the computer today and this is my breakdown at the end of day
Apps - 6.6 GB 
Documents - 1.01 GB
Messages - 1.5 MB
Photos - 1.6 MB
---
macOS - 15.23 GB
System Data 12.19 GB 

So deleting the cached items did help, but basically NOT SYNCING the iCloud Drive is the real deal.

Comment: I don't mind syncing iCloud Drive, if I can find out how to get rid of its 90gb of system data baggage.

Comment: Also, I have used OmniDiskSweeper multiple times before I decided to do the factory reboot, ;) Thanks for the suggestion though! It's my favorite tool as well!!!

Comment: @RachelChung My point is that the OS will now start to recreate the caches, eating up whatever space you gained by deleting them.